# Show the symmetric difference of two git branches?

Tags: git, git-branch

I'm looking for some way to get all commits that are either on branch `A` or on branch `B`, but not on both of them.

Comment: Are you looking to show all commits in two branches which have not yet been combined.

Comment: I guess you could rephrase it that way, yes.

Comment: You could try this(triple dot operator)# show all commits which can be reached by master or testing but not both
git log master...testing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already stated in a comment, the triple-dot operator gives the answer. Quoting `man git-rev-parse`:

> A similar notation "r1...r2" is called symmetric difference of r1 and
>   r2 and is defined as "r1 r2 --not $(git merge-base --all r1 r2)". It
>   is the set of commits that are reachable from either one of r1 or r2
>   but not from both.